# What is a monotone dataset and monotone classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Classification algorithms, such as k-Nearest Neighbors, are well known in machine learning area, but I faced this new expression **Monotone classification** and I wonder what does it stand for.

I guess that it has something to do with some peculiar characteristic of the dataset, e.g. if all the objects have growing attributes and, plotted in a 2D plane, they look as if they were gathered around the line of the function *f(x) = x* or something like this, but as english is not my native language, I couldn't understand the raw meaning of **Monotone** and **Monotone classifiers**, the things I read were so confusing that I don't think it is worth it to mention.

I read this:

> The evaluation of teaching courses based on surveys gathered from
>   students’ opinions can be categorized as a monotonic classification
>   problem if it intends to predict a final qualification that summarizes
>   the general quality of the course. The students are asked to evaluate
>   each course according to several aspects related to interest,
>   achieving appropriate class participation, teaching resources,
>   capabilities of the teacher, etc.

I would like to be able to say why these surveys behave as a monotone dataset, but no explanation fits what I have in mind about the monotone definition.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function

Comment: I know what is a monotonic *function*, is just a function that always x <= y, then f(x) <= f(y), I wanna know what is a monotonic *DATA SET*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *monotone classifier* is a classifier that is a [monotonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

One reasonable definition of *monotone data set* is that it is a data set that is consistent with some monotone model (i.e., where there exists a monotone classifier that gets 100% accuracy).  I don't know if this is a standard definition so hopefully any text that uses that phrase would provide a definition.

Why use a monotone classifier in the setting you mention? Perhaps we have some a priori reason for believing that, all else being equal, the higher the students rate their satisfaction, the higher the quality of the course.  That amounts to a monotonicity assumption about the underlying model that relates quality to satisfaction.  If we assume that the data was generated from a monotone model, it is reasonable to try to learn a monotone classifier.  Whether this is appropriate in any particular setting depends on whether you have a reason to think that the data does come from a monotone process/model or not.

Answer (score -1):

I don't find any difference between the conventional classifiers we use with the definition of a monotone classifier

Comment: Could you support this with some reference?

Comment: There may be difference in the sense that you can easily understand if an object is an outlier, since it is a monotonic dataset.